# Javascript shows me TypeError saying my variable is undefined

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to code a simple Javascript exercise where I have to place different text at different part of the page but it keeps throwing me a

```js
TypeError:sal[0] is undefined
```

Here is the javascript code.

```js
function sals(a,b,c,d,e,id)
{
    var sal = document.getElementsByClassName(id);
    sal[0].style.top=a;
    sal[0].style.left=b;
    sal[0].style.color=c;
    sal[0].style.fontsize=d;
    sal[0].style.zindex=e;
}

 sals('5%','50%','yellow','250px','20','GB');
```

What am I doing wrong?

For further reference, here is my HTML code aswell

```html
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="GB"> Holla</h1>
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Comment: Move your script  after the h1 tag

Comment: As Martinez said, the script should be at the bottom of the body. Otherwise the script will load and try to find the `h1` element before it has loaded, causing it to give an `undefined` error.

Comment: Looks like your javascript is probably running before the DOM (HTML structure) is fully loaded, while moving the script after the tag is one possible solution you can also trigger your function on DOM loaded. In vanilla javascript you can use `document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   sal('5%','50%','yellow','250px','20','GB');
}, false);`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Your JavaScript is running before the page (DOM) has fully loaded.

the simplest way to make sure the DOM is loaded before your JS runs, is to add 'defer' to the script tag thus;-

```
<head>
<title>Hello</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
<script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<body>   
<h1 class="GB"> Holla</h1>
</body>
</html>
```